# Android SIP: Service not running for incoming sip calls

Tags: android, service, sip-server

I am developing a SIP application for VOIP calls. I have modified SIPDemo as per my UI requirements. When an incoming call is triggered, my app is registered to server domain and able to receive calls, (even in the case when the app is not running).
But when my app is destroyed/killed, incoming calls are not triggered. 
I have made service start, i think its not running. I'm new to this and unable to figure out, Kindly suggest the help!

> **Manifest Declaration:**

***For Service:***

```
  <service
        android:name=".CallDetectService"
        android:process=".com.example.mysip.callservice"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" >
    </service>
```

***For Receiver:***

```
   <receiver
        android:name=".receiver.ServiceAtBootReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

***Manifest Permissions:***

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_SIP" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.sip.voip"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.microphone"
    android:required="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

all your manifest declarations are good,,, and as for keeping your app running that depends on how well your service is made... here is an answer that I hope it helps you:
[AlarmManager or Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605109/alarmmanager-or-service/19657581#19657581)