# How to avoid killing and restarting the service and process when app is swiped to right in Overview(a.k.a recent apps screen) screen?

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding, android-recents

I am seeing my app in the following screen

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbqqZ.jpg

If I swipe my app to the right, I notice that the process and services related to app are killed.

1. How to avoid killing the process and services when we swipe?
2. How to keep the service (I am using IntentService - so other
   [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26842675/continue-service-even-if-application-is-cleared-from-recent-app/41257604#41257604) mentioned for similar question doesn't work) running
   when the app is swiped to right?
3. Answer mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26842675/continue-service-even-if-application-is-cleared-from-recent-app/41257604#41257604) restarts (which means the service doesn't do
       its job for few seconds during the restart phase) the service and
       process. I want the service to work continuously without any drop.
       How to do this?

Comment: IntentServices are not meant to be used for long running stuff. Also, why did you tag android-service-binding? IntentServices are not meant to be bound.

Comment: I thought android-service-binding might be a new solution (moving entirely out of Intent services) for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to start your service as a foreground service. Refer [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) under Running a service in the foreground.

If you start the service which is a background service, Android will kill it whenever memory is low. And take note, not every time that list is cleared, your service will die. It happens only when the Android system decides its low on memory.

Comment: I went through that option. Thanks. But Is it possible to create a foreground service without notification ?

Comment: according to this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10962418/how-to-startforeground-without-showing-notification

its not possible and not adviced as well.

Comment: I was just reading that. My app is liek Facebook or Whatsapp where if a message is sent, it has to be shown immediately to the user. For that the app has to be continuously talking to my web server. So the service that talks to web server should always be up and running (there shouldn't be no restart - user forcefully killing is fine).

Comment: I just read this https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/1uqpwv/a_query_about_android_service_startforeground/cel9mdg/  I think push notifications would work. Any suggestions on push notifications for my use case.