# Background service crashes the app after killing application

Tags: android, xamarin

I am using a background service in my application to get the location updates,
Everything works great, but when I kill the app (from the recent screen), it displays a message that "Unfortunately app has stopped",while returning the sticky service,I realized that after killing the app, my background service restarts but it crashes my application

Comment: post ur logcat. and service also.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) link to know more about asking questions here on SO as your question isn't very descriptive or doesn't includes samples of your efforts or examples.

Comment: I suspect the service is bounded service, if yes can you please post the src here? like how you are binding it and unbinding it

Comment: Please post your  `Service` code.

Answer (score 0):

your service and processes (Threads run inside your service) will remain continuous.
Redirecting you to the same question [Continue Service even if application is cleared from Recent app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26842675/continue-service-even-if-application-is-cleared-from-recent-app/41257604#41257604)