# Foreground service stopping in some mobiles when app destroyed

Tags: android, foreground-service

Foreground service stopping in some mobiles when app destroyed, want to run foreground service even app destoryed.

### Manifest :

```
<service android:name=".services.LocationService" />
```

### Here is how i am starting and stopping service :

```
private void startLocationUpdates() {
    if (!isMyServiceRunning(LocationService.class)) {

        Intent locationServiceIntent = new Intent(this, LocationService.class);
        locationServiceIntent.putExtra(StringConstants.LOCATION_UPDATES, true);

        startService(locationServiceIntent);
    }
}

private void stopLocationUpdates() {
    Intent locationServiceIntent = new Intent(this, LocationService.class);
    locationServiceIntent.putExtra(StringConstants.LOCATION_UPDATES, false);

    startService(locationServiceIntent);
}
```

### Service :

```
public class LocationService extends Service {
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Service started");
    if (intent != null) {
      if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        startForeground(1, notification);

      } else {

        startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyForeGroundService.class));

    }
    }
    return START_STICKY;
```

}
}

```
private NotificationCompat.Builder getNotificationBuilder(){
    return new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentIntent(MyApp.pendingIntent)
            .setContentText("setContentText")
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_black_24px))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_black_24px);
}
```

Comment: Kindly go through this [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask]

Comment: Can you include code what you have tried so far? @Anil Kolla

Comment: Where did you include the code @AnilKolla

Comment: @g.brahmaDatta Added the code above in the post,Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this one @AnilKolla https://stackoverflow.com/a/41257604/7352857

Comment: @g.brahmaDatta stackoverflow.com/a/41257604/7352857 this is also not working, still same problem after app destroying service stopped, this issue occuring in most of oppo, vivo mobiles.

Comment: You shouldn't do anything on android device without giving the user a method to cancel.  Do nothing mean.  Don't wreck the battery life.  Play fair and see if that works.

Comment: @danny117, thanks for your suggestion but your answer not suitable for my question.

Comment: @AnilKolla Running things in the background without letting the user know has never been a best practice.  Of course the OS will end your service if you don't inform the users.

Comment: @danny117, i am running foreground service not background, it will show notification to user whenever it is running.

Comment: I didn't know that foreground service includes and automatic notification to the user.

Comment: @danny117, we will throw notification to user, not service.

Answer (score 0):

for devices having OS Oreo and above there is a limitation in running service , you have to show a notification for devices having Oreo and above ,you have to do one more thing instead of `startService()` try using `startForegroundService()` for more info please go through the official doc https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background

Comment: i am doing same as what you are saying, still there is issue.

Comment: but it does not look like you are doing the same as above code snippet.

Comment: Please check my post now

Comment: Before starting service check android version if its oreo and above then call startForgroundService() else call startService()

Comment: Once again look into my code Sujeet, still i am facing same issue.