# Continue service even when app is cleared from recent apps or closed on Red MI Device

Tags: java, android-service, redmi-device

I am running a telemetry service in my app. This service is checking for changes in WiFi environment once a second and if changes are detected it notifies a remote db. I need this service to continue running even if the app is swiped from recent apps or closed.

I followed [Continue Service even if application is cleared from Recent app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26842675/continue-service-even-if-application-is-cleared-from-recent-app) and it seems to work on many devices except for Xiaomi. I've tried many things advised for this device:

1. enable auto-start.
2. disable battery optimization for that app.
3. Tried using a broadcast receiver to start the service
4. Tried using timer thread and scheduleExecutorservice instead of runnable. didn't make a difference.

This is my latest sample code :

```
package com.example.csi1;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.wifi.SupplicantState;
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainService extends Service {
    public Context context = this;
    public Handler handler = null;
    public static Runnable runnable = null;
    public static int count = 0;
    public int restart = 0;
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        Toast.makeText(this, "MainService onStartCommand", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        count = 0;

        handler = new Handler();
        runnable = new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                count = count+1;

                WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                WifiInfo wifiInfo;

                wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
                if (wifiInfo.getSupplicantState() == SupplicantState.COMPLETED) {
                    String ssid = wifiInfo.getSSID();
                    Log.i("Service", "SSID:"+ssid);
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Service iter " + String.valueOf(count)+ " " + ssid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG );
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.RIGHT, 0, 0);
                    toast.show();
                }

                handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);

            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 3000);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "onTaskRemoved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (restart == 0) {
            PendingIntent service = PendingIntent.getService(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    1001,
                    new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainService.class),
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 1000, service);
            restart=1;
            Toast.makeText(this, "Service restarted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        Toast.makeText(this, "onDestroy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (restart == 0) {
            PendingIntent service = PendingIntent.getService(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    1001,
                    new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainService.class),
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 1000, service);
            restart=1;
            Toast.makeText(this, "Service restarted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }
}
```

it runs fine on Samsung device and google nexus emulator,  but whenever i run it on Red mi and swipe the app from recent apps,app dies and service with it. Is there a solution for Red mi devices or this is some well known limitation ?

Answer (score 0):

Xiaomi's MIUI and a couple of others are very aggressive on removing background services. As a user you are able to disable it following [these steps (for xiaomi)](https://www.freakyjolly.com/how-to-run-background-service-in-xiaomi-mobiles/). But I am not aware of a solution to circumvent it as a developer.

So you're not doing anything wrong, some phones just don't like background services taking battery life. Similar discussion can be found here: ["Protected Apps" setting on Huawei phones, and how to handle it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31638986/protected-apps-setting-on-huawei-phones-and-how-to-handle-it). Their solution is basically having the user disable it by calling the optimization manager for each of the [problematic devices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51726040/11702000)

Comment: Thank you Software person. I've done these steps but the service still gets killed, so i understand that the os will simply not let me restart it ?

Comment: In general yes, but maybe check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35220476/11702000. And see if that helps.