# issue : Service is destroyed on Killing the app

Tags: android, service, background, android-mediaplayer

As per my Searching :

To run a service in back ground you have to create a STICKY service with flag START_STICKY.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
  // Do your task here
  return START_STICKY;
 }
```

An START_STICKY service can run in background without any activity presence . And you can communicate with service with callbacks.

But, the issue is :

When I killed the application, And Since I am using START_STICKY, onCreate() and onStartCommand() method called again.

But, What If I wanna to continue running service without destroying it when application killed ?

Actually, I am using media player.
code is as below :

Service :

```
public class MyService extends Service {

private MediaPlayer media;

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Toast.makeText(this, "on create", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    media = MediaPlayer.create(this, Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI);
    media.setLooping(true);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "on start command", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (media!=null && !media.isPlaying()) {
        media.start();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "media is not playing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    media.stop();
    Toast.makeText(this, "service on destroy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Service Calls :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void startMethod(View v) {
    startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
}

public void stopMethod(View v) {
    stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
}
```

}

**So, How media player keeps running without any stop ?** Right now, it stops when i am killing the app and starting again when onCreate() and onStartCommand() methods of Service is calling again since i am using START_STICKY.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20592366/the-process-of-the-service-is-killed-after-the-application-is-removed-from-the-a

Comment: Use Foreground Service.

Comment: okay, thanks. Any specified or helpful demo for media player using Foreground service ?