# Need to run a service even after the activity is destroyed in android

Tags: android, android-service

I have tried using **START_STICKY** on the `onStartCommand()` method of intent services, I have even tried changing the process name of the service on the `manifest.xml` file. But none works. Whenever I kill the app, the service also gets destroyed. I want to design a service that gets triggered when the user starts the app for the first time and then keeps on running even after user kills the application. Any help will be useful

Comment: Well explained in this so answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20592366/the-process-of-the-service-is-killed-after-the-application-is-removed-from-the-a#20781110

Comment: what's your mobile name and android version?

Comment: Please add the code that fails.

Answer (score 2):

In service class implement on destroy method which will trigger a broadcast. In that broadcast receiver class implement on receive method. So whenever service destroyed this broadcast receiver class will execute onreceive method. In that onreceive method start the service again.

Answer (score 1):

Your service must be in the foreground to prevent the system from closing it. See the `startForeground` method in the `Service` class.